# Learning laravel - advanced

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've been lately learning laravel. I've read many articles and the book Code Bright. I've also practiced laravel.

However, t. I feel that there are some things that laravel has to offer that I don't know about. I couldn't really understand the real usage for the `Event` class, more advanced `Eloquent` methods and generally, I feel like I've learned laravel, I know how to use it, but I don't know how to make it mine (None of the books/articles I've read were actually deep explaining about some Route methods, such as Resource or Controller and their advantages or disatvatages). I'm not necessarily talking about changing laravel settings and swapping directories. I just want to learn more about it including practical examples.

Do you guys have any book/videos/articles that you can recommend me buy/view/read?

Thanks!

P.S. Any book/video/article that is showing how to build some application is good since I can learn a lot from that

Comment: have you checked https://laracasts.com/ ?

Comment: To understand advanced laravel I always read the [`API`](http://laravel.com/api/). There are many things is not explained in the documentation or articles. The code explained by itself.

Comment: @cornelb Yes I have. Still, some things are missing, the photo is not fully cleared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, **[Laracasts.com](http://laracasts.com)** is a **great** resource for learning Laravel specifically, but good PHP and general development practices in general.

There are a **lot** of great tutorials by [Phillip Brown](https://twitter.com/philipbrown) over at http://culttt.com/code where he documents building the open source http://cribbb.com/ app.

**[Laravel.io](http://laravel.io)** has an awesome, active forum with many super smart Laravel folks.

As for books? Of course Dayle Rees' Code Bright, but you already mentioned it. There's also:

- Taylor Otwell's [Laravel: From Apprentice To Artisan](https://leanpub.com/laravel)
- Chris Fidao's [Implementing Laravel](https://leanpub.com/implementinglaravel)
- Christopher Pitt and's [Laravel 4 Cookbook](https://leanpub.com/laravel4cookbook)
- Jeffrey Way's [Laravel Testing Decoded](https://leanpub.com/laravel-testing-decoded).

There is so much info available for Laravel and I think you have barely scratched the surface!

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking, I've barely scratched the surface. Thanks a lot! I will be reading Implementing Laravel. I will also look at the other resources that you've mentioned. About Culttt.com/code, there are tons of tutorials, which one of them did recommend that shows how he built the cribbb app?

Comment: The amount of Laravel info available is staggering, but the community is great and very helpful. The Cribbb app lessons start here I think: http://culttt.com/2013/04/29/getting-started-with-laravel-4/ but you should be able to find them all here: http://culttt.com/tag/cribbb/page/7/ That will take you to the oldest posts, and then work your way back.

Comment: cribbb.com seems dead.

Answer (score 0):

[Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/) is a great resource to use when you want delve into the functionality that Laravel offers you.

Comment: I know Laracasts, however, I'm looking for a more organized source, I will make sure to go through everything in Laracasts, but still, any other recommendations are welcome

Comment: http://culttt.com/ also has pretty awesome tutorials